# Webjob application vs web api app triggered by console app as a web job

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I have a web api(.netcore) which I have hosted in Azure under an app service.

I have another app related to the above api(in the same resource group) which need to be triggered every few minutes.

My confusion is what is the best practise?

1) Write a webjob app(.net framework) for the second app.

2) Write the second app as an api and write a console app to call the api. Then call the console app from the webjobs in Azure. But that would mean a second app service in the same resource group(for second API).

Is there any pricing difference between the two?

Is there any advantage of one over the other?

Is there any better way?

**Update**

I have gone with the second option.

[image]

Is there any advantage if I go with the below(cost and code vice).So in the same app service there will be a wep app, a webjob to trigger the api and another webjob to read message from queue do the processing.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a pretty decent use case for [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/).

Comment: @liroforum I think the first thing is that you must describe your purpose clearly about two app and their relationship. Then, people can know how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options for writing a service that is triggered on a timer:

1. WebJobs - These are essentially console apps that run behind the scenes to do related jobs that users of your API don't need to wait on (photo processing is a common example) or need to be run on a schedule, like your use case.
2. Azure Functions - Functions are similar to WebJobs, but make it easier to scale and abstract away the necessity of coding up connections to a lot of other services. They also can have billing advantages if you are creating an App Service just to run them.
3. Azure Logic Apps - I think you want either WebJobs or Functions, but Logic Apps can also run a job on a schedule. In this case, you are designing your workflow either in JSON file or more likely in a GUI. If your job doesn't require much custom code, using a Logic App means that development time is reduced and you have one less piece of custom code to maintain.

For pricing:

- Both Webjobs and Functions can be attached to the same App Service account as your API as long as you have sufficient resources there to handle the additional load. So no additional costs there.
- You could pay for a separate App Service account for the Webjob if you want, but usually they are kept on the same App Service account as the API.
- Functions apps can run on a special type of App Service account that has a [consumption plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/). What that means that instead of a monthly fee, you pay for the resources that you actually use.
- Logic Apps aren't connected to App Services, and have consumption based billing similar to Functions.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. it does make more send now. So I have gone with the webjobs option. I have also updated my question. Do you have any idea cost vise how much difference will be there?

Comment: Cost is attached to the App Service account, not a specific webjob or website. So the cost will be determined based on how that is configured, not the individual applications. That said, if you have automatic scaling turned on, more stuff running means more likely that the scaling will kick in.

Comment: so does that mean, if I have 2 web app services, one with an api and the other one with just the webjobs. I will be charged only for the 1st app service, as I believe the webjobs does not incur a cost. Or will I be charged for 2 web app services?

Comment: In the case of Webjobs and Webapps, the App Service is billed at a given rate based on the allocated resources regardless of what is running on them. So you could have your API and both Webjobs running on a single App Service account without any cost beyond that single plan. If you run the Webjobs on a separate App Service account then you have to pay for that second account.

Comment: Still a bit confused. So I have a single app service plan and 4 app service(2 for the web api's and 2 for the webjobs to trigger the API's). Is there any advantage in combining 2 web jobs with 2 web api's so that I have only 2 app service under the 1 appservice plan? Or would cost the same for 2 or 4 Appservice if they are under the same App service Plan?

Comment: And what did you mean by "In the case of Webjobs and Webapps, the App Service is billed at a given rate based on the allocated resources regardless of what is running on them". Did you mean the memory the app services are allocated when they were created?

Comment: The App Service plan is what determines cost. The plan allocates a certain amount of memory and CPU for whatever you decide to run on it. There is no additional cost for running multiple Web Apps, APIs or WebJobs within the plan. It sounds like you are only running a single plan, so that is what you are being billed for.